# Nodemailer sending mail again after 8 hours

Tags: node.js, winston, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer module to send mail from the node server when users request for a new password using the following function:

```
function(email, password, callback) {
    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'something@gmail.com',
            pass: 'my_password'
        }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'My Team<something@gmail.com>',
        to: email,
        subject: 'new password',
        text: 'login with email: ' + email + 'and password: ' + password,
        html: '<p>login with email: ' + email + ' and password: ' + password +
              '<br> Visit here to learn more ' + ' <a href=\"www.google.com\">google</a></p>'
    };

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, res) {
        if(err) {
            smtpTransport.close();
            return callback(err);

        } else {
            smtpTransport.close();
            return callback(null);
        }
    });
};
```

The email id I am using is a valid one. The user indeed gets a mail from this id containing a newly generated random password. However, he again gets a mail after exactly 8 hours containing yet another newly generated random password. I don't know how this function is called again after 8 hours on the server side.

I am using winston for logging all api calls and the data received in the request object. However the timestamp format is unfamiliar to me. How do I convert this 
    "timestamp":"2013-09-13T19:39:16.814Z" logged by winston to my local time? Also due to asynchronous nature of node.js the order in which api calls are logged is all interleaved and messed up. How do I log the api calls in the order they are called and served?